# htaccess: nested wordpress folder redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

I've been trying for hours and am already a bit on the edge about this, so I am probably not seeing the obvious.

I have two WordPress sites, one is my "main" page which people see when they come to my domain root, and one is a private blog:

`www.example.com` and `www.example.com/blog`

On my server root, I would like to keep both pages organized in separate folders, to keep it clean. These folders I named `wp-main` and `wp-blog`. To redirect the domains I started fiddling with `.htaccess`, but I can't seem to get it right - `blog` is the problem. `main` works fine with instructions from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory), but the blog doesn't load the WordPress theme (displays raw content), and does not redirect to any subfolders. If I take away the redirect rules for `main`, the blog index gets loaded, but still no subfolder redirect.

Can anybody help me out here?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## redirect for main
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-main($|/)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog($|/)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-main/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp-main/index.php 

## redirect for blog
RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ /wp-blog/$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have more than one domain?

Comment: sorry, I missed that earlier - it's only one domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-main($|/)$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog($|/)$
> ```

You should remove the `$` (end-of-string anchor) at the end of these two *CondPatterns*. Otherwise, requests for `/blog/<something>` will get routed to `/wp-main/...`, since the above condition is satisfied (since it *does not* match the pattern `^/blog($|/)$`).

Consider reversing your logic and rewrite `/blog` (the more *specific* URL) first. (And use `L` flags to prevent additional processing.)

---

**UPDATE:** Try the following instead...

I've reversed the logic, so that `/blog` is handled first (the *more specific* URL). This avoids you having to explicitly *avoid* `/blog` when rewriting the main site. I've also assumed that you only have one domain (which I asked about in my earlier comment) - this avoids the requirement to check the `Host` header (ie. `HTTP_HOST` server variable). If you do have more than one domain on your account then your current directives were incomplete anyway.

You do not need the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper, unless your site is intended to function without mod_rewrite (it is not).

Potentially, all you need is:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite blog site
RewriteRule ^blog/?(.*)$ /wp-blog/$1 [L]

# Rewrite everything else to the main site
RewriteRule (.*) /wp-main/$1 [L]
```

A few assumptions:

- Each subdirectory (`/wp-blog` and `/wp-main`) has its own `.htaccess` file (with mod_rewrite directives) - this prevents a rewrite loop.
- There are no static resources outside of these WordPress installations. All static resources are also rewritten. eg. `/images/foo.jpg` is internally rewritten to `/wp-main/images/foo.jpg` and `/blog/images/foo.jpg` is rewritten to `/wp-blog/images/foo.jpg` etc. You never reference `/wp-main` or `/wp-blog` directly in client-side HTML. If there are shared static resources in other locations (eg. a `/scripts` subdirectory off the real document root) then you will either need an additional filesystem check (if there are too may locations to list) or include an exception for this location, before the existing directives. For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^scripts/ - [L]
  ```
- Both `/blog` and `/blog/` (with a slash) access your blog homepage (this avoids `/blog` being rewritten to your main site). Ideally, only `/blog/` should access your blog and `/blog` would redirect to this. This can be achieved with an additional redirect before the blog rewrite:

  ```
  # Rewrite blog site
  RewriteRule ^(blog)$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
  RewriteRule ^blog/?(.*)$ /wp-blog/$1 [L]
  ```

  Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only when you are sure this is what you want and have confirmed that it works OK. 301s are cached persistently by the browser.

---

Then, each `.htaccess` file in the respective subdirectory should be of the form:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

No need to specify the `RewriteBase` or include the subdirectory in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

Comment: Thanks! Now blog and its index display correctly. I put `RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ /wp-blog/$1 [L]` after `RewriteBase /`. However, what is still not working is the subfolder redirect for `blog`: if I click on one of my blogposts, I end up with "Page not found", but in the `main` layout. Any guess?

Comment: "the subfolder redirect for `blog`" - I'm not sure what you mean? Have you changed the URL structure in WordPress itself to reference `/blog/....`?

Comment: what I mean was that if I click on anything that goes beyond `/blog/` (e.g. "mydomain.net/blog/entry1" in the url, I end up with a "Page NOT Found" error. the error is displayed as part of the `main`-wordpress page. does that make sense?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ /wp-blog/$1 [L]` - This will result in a double slash in the rewritten URL, which could be a potential problem, although this shouldn't result in the request appearing on the "main" site? What do you have in the subdirectory/WordPress `.htaccess` files? I've updated my answer.

Comment: sweet, that did it, many thanks for your answer! indeed, there are some shared files between the sites. I added `RewriteRule ^(wp-shared|wp-files)($|/) - [L]` before the rules in the root htaccess

regarding your last point (`/blog` or `/blog/` taking me to the "blog" site), this already worked without me specifiying this anywhere...